# Show names from two values

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a SQL code but can't really figure out how to do it so I will explain what I want.

I have 4 tables called Person, Customer, Adres and Store. Now I have to show each customer NAMES which lives in the same city as where there is a Store. So First I figured out which persons are customers by:

```
SELECT person_name
FROM person
WHERE person_id IN
(SELECT Person_Person_Id
FROM customer);
```

Which stores are in which city:

```
SELECT Store_name, adres_city
FROM store s, adres a
WHERE s.Adres_Adres_Id = a.adres_id;
```

Note that person_person_id is the same as person_id just as a fk.

I am stuck at this code and don''t know how to go further from here. My column name of table adres = adres_city.

Comment: Do you wanna display the data of a especific city or grouped by the citys?

Comment: I want to show the names of the person who live in same city as where the store is located... 

So only names of persons is needed

Comment: Could you tell me what are the columns in the customer table, please?

Comment: person_id, person_firstname, person_lastname, person_email, person_phone, person_gender and adres_adres_id

Comment: You are inputing the person name twice? The first in the table person and then the second in the costumer table? The columns above are from the customer table, right?

Comment: Please write which attributes are joined tables and which fields to use.

Comment: Person is joined with Customer and Adres.
Store is only joined with Adres.

Comment: As explained... The store has a city and each person lives in a city. I want to show all the persons who live in the same city as the store is located... IF the person lives in another city than any store is located the person should not been shown as output.

Each person (from table person) can be a seller, customer etc etc. I already figured out to show all persons who are only customer in the first statement. and I figured out which stores are in which cities.

Comment: Okay, in this case you need to join tables customer_city a join store_city b
on a.city_name = b.city_name(or you can use city_id). If you want me to write a query for you let me now. But I'll need table names and column names in this case.

Comment: Table 
**Persoon:** 
person_id, person_firstname, person_lastname, person_email, person_phone, person_gender and adres_adres_id 

**Customer:**
Person_Person_Id, Customer_Bankaccount

**Adres:**
Adres_Id, Adres_Street, Adres_Number, Adres_Letter, Adres_ZIP, Adres_City, Adres_State, Adres_Country

**Store:**
Store_Id, Store_Code, Store_name, Store_description, Adres_Adres_Id

Comment: I hope this is enough

Comment: NOTE: Customer does not have a relation with adres. Person does

Answer (score 1):

Okay, if I realised what do you want, try to do this:

```
select --distinct   
    b.Adres_City,
    a.person_id 
from 
    dbo.Person a 
    join dbo.Adres b on a.adres_adres_id = b.Adres_Id
    join dbo.Customer c on a.person_id = c.Person_Person_Id
    join dbo.Store d on b.Adres_Id = d.Adres_Adres_Id
```

If you are not sure, that all your keys in tables are uniq, uncomment --distinct in the first string.

Or, if you are want to know statistics among your cities, do this:

```
select 
    b.Adres_City,
    count(distinct a.person_id) as cnt
from 
    dbo.Person a 
    join dbo.Adres b on a.adres_adres_id = b.Adres_Id
    join dbo.Customer c on a.person_id = c.Person_Person_Id
    join dbo.Store d on b.Adres_Id = d.Adres_Adres_Id
group by b.Adres_City
```

Please let me know, if it will help you.

Update1:

```
select --distinct   
    b.Adres_City,
    a.person_id 
from 
    dbo.Person a 
    join dbo.Adres b on a.adres_adres_id = b.Adres_Id
    join dbo.Customer c on a.person_id = c.Person_Person_Id
where 
    b.Adres_City in (
        select y.Adres_City
        from dbo.Store x join dbo.Adres y on y.Adres_Id = x.Adres_Adres_Id
    )
```

Comment: it says DBO.person does not exist same voor adres, customer and store

Comment: I removed the DBO and it works... But doesn't show any output.

Comment: If its not difficult, please give me an example about one client from all of this tables, which should be in the output.

Comment: output: persons (names) who lives in the same city as the store is located.

So first I want to check if the person is a customer. if it is the city where this person lives has to be the as the city of the store.

all addresses are in one big table so there has to be a comparsion between the persons (city) and store (city). If there are persons who live in the same city as the store is located the output should show all the persons names.

Comment: Check Update1 please.

Comment: Omg hero! Thankyou very much!!